# Why does the turbulence effect cease after 60 frames?

Tags: particles, force-fields

I have particles that are affected by turbulence. The turbulence is apparent until around frame 60 or so, then they go back to moving as usual.

Have tried playing around with things like adding a 16m minimum falloff distance, but it seems to be irrespective of distance.

What might be going on? Don't remember this happening with turbulence before (I am using in combination with harmonics and other force fields).

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Comment: Does the physics cache have the proper start and end frame?

Comment: Since I don't know how your particles move (or they should move, because I don't see any change around frame 60) I can just guessing - some cache mish-mash - change number of particles +/-1 ... or Delete and Bake cache.